# Hibernate Caching not update after adding some records

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, orm

when I selecting some set of data using from Hibernate Session it will listed all data. after that I'll add new records it was added but I try to get data again but there are not available last I added. here is my code.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iposLite?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Grn" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.GrnDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.GrnRetrunDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.GrnReturn" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Invoice" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.InvoiceDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.InvoiceReturn" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.InvoiceReturnDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Item" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Ledger" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.LedgerDetail" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Receipt" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Stock" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Supplier" />
        <mapping class="com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.User" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Item.java model class

```
package com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author Hashan Chamikara
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i")})
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "barcode")
    private String barcode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "unit")
    private String unit;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "unit_description")
    private String unitDescription;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "expire")
    private int expire;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "warranty")
    private int warranty;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "modify")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modify;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetailList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Stock> stockList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<GrnDetail> grnDetailList;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item(Integer id, String barcode, String reference, String name, String category, String unit, int expire, int warranty, int status, Date created, Date modify) {
        this.id = id;
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.reference = reference;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.expire = expire;
        this.warranty = warranty;
        this.status = status;
        this.created = created;
        this.modify = modify;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getUnitDescription() {
        return unitDescription;
    }

    public void setUnitDescription(String unitDescription) {
        this.unitDescription = unitDescription;
    }

    public int getExpire() {
        return expire;
    }

    public void setExpire(int expire) {
        this.expire = expire;
    }

    public int getWarranty() {
        return warranty;
    }

    public void setWarranty(int warranty) {
        this.warranty = warranty;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getModify() {
        return modify;
    }

    public void setModify(Date modify) {
        this.modify = modify;
    }

    public List<InvoiceDetail> getInvoiceDetailList() {
        return invoiceDetailList;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDetailList(List<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetailList) {
        this.invoiceDetailList = invoiceDetailList;
    }

    public List<Stock> getStockList() {
        return stockList;
    }

    public void setStockList(List<Stock> stockList) {
        this.stockList = stockList;
    }

    public List<GrnDetail> getGrnDetailList() {
        return grnDetailList;
    }

    public void setGrnDetailList(List<GrnDetail> grnDetailList) {
        this.grnDetailList = grnDetailList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item other = (Item) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.models.Item[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

DatabaseUtil.java

```
package com.isimple.intelijpos_lite.util;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author chamikara
 */
public class DatabaseUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Item Save Method

```
public boolean saveItem(Item item, Stock stock) {
        Session session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.save(item);
            session.save(stock);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return transaction.wasCommitted();
    }
```

Item List Method

```
  public List<Item> searchItem(String text) {
        Session session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List list = session.createCriteria(Item.class).add(
                Restrictions.and(
                        Restrictions.or(
                                Restrictions.like("barcode", text, MatchMode.START),
                                Restrictions.like("reference", text, MatchMode.START),
                                Restrictions.like("name", text, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)),
                        Restrictions.eq("status", Const.ITEM_ACTIVE)))
                .setMaxResults(20).list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }
```

Application run in same thread

Before Adding Test 2 Item

[image]
Adding Item

[image]

After Adding Item

[image]

Comment: After you add an item, can you query the database (using MySQL Workbench or command line) and see if it got added successfully?

Comment: Yes It will added to database but I try to query in hibernate but it'll not showing.  I think hibernate using caching there for I off the cashing in hibernate.cfg.xml however it'll not stopped